# SQL syntax error in mysql_query SELECT statement

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql syntax error that tells me this: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= 'upVote'' at line 1"

Here is my code:

```
    $likedQuery = mysql_query("SELECT Liked FROM " . $cookie . "WHERE type = 'upVote'", $dbh2) or die (mysql_error());
$likedArray = mysql_fetch_array($likedQuery);

$allLikes = $likedArray['Liked'];
```

Comment: Type is a keyword. Escape it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about syntax errors

Comment: @karthikr Was just checking ... it's not on [the list](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) but a good idea nontheless

Comment: what is the value of $cookie

Comment: The value of $cookie is a username. Each user has a database table.

Comment: Ohh yeah and obligitory [mysql_* is bad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php/14110189#14110189) comment. All the cool kids are switching to [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [pdo](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: @karthikr `type` is not a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html).

Comment: @ArnarKjartansson That comment turns this from "suspicious looking code" into "a database design that's clearly wrong"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a space before the `WHERE`, change:

```
$likedQuery = mysql_query("SELECT Liked FROM " . $cookie . "WHERE type = 'upVote'", $dbh2) or die (mysql_error());
```

to:

```
$likedQuery = mysql_query("SELECT Liked FROM " . $cookie . " WHERE type = 'upVote'", $dbh2) or die (mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a space after your table name

```
$likedQuery = mysql_query("SELECT `Liked` FROM `" . $cookie . "` WHERE `type` = 'upVote'", $dbh2) or die (mysql_error());
$likedArray = mysql_fetch_array($likedQuery);

$allLikes = $likedArray['Liked'];
```

And it's always a good idea to escape your field and table identifiers with a backtick

Answer (score 0):

you probably need a space between $cookie and your WHERE

```
$cookie . " " . WHERE
```